# Maven and db4o dependency

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, dependencies, db4o

I'm intrigued to test new frameworks in the Java world, and decided to create a new project that takes advantage of Maven and db4o. I'm starting to get a hang of Maven, but I have a hard time adding db4o as a dependency to the project. First problem is that db4o doesn't exist in the official Maven repositories. Next up comes the problem that db4o seem to have recently restructured their whole site's URI:s, so I'm getting 'site not found' messages all the time when I try to navigate their site.

I found somewhere a potential Maven repository that should be at https://source.db4o.com/maven but I get all the time "Error reading archetype catalog https://source.db4o.com/maven Unable to locate resource in repository" when I try to access it.

So, any suggestions on how I'll get db4o up through Maven? I've managing Maven through Eclipse with the M2Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Works for me with the following snippet:

```
<project>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>source.db4o</id>
      <url>http://source.db4o.com/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  ...

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.db4o</groupId>
      <artifactId>db4o-full-java5</artifactId>
      <version>8.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- latest version -->
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Seens like manually adding the dependency did it. Did not just pop up in the GUIs of M2Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if they plan to add the actual sources to the repo as well? When I click on a class, I want maven to upload the sources, but no luck... They aren't there

Comment: Versant got bought by Actian. They have discontinued their work on db4o. Therefore the link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

You won't see a dependency in m2eclipse unless the Maven repository has been indexed with the Nexus indexer...very few 3rd party repositories are.