# Can't download project dependency (db4o) from Maven: cert error

Tags: java, netbeans, ssl, https, maven

I have a Maven project and added db4o as a dependency using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303424/maven-and-db4o-dependency/2303479#2303479) from a previous question. When I compile the project it gives me the following error:

> Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project
>   org.uca.dss:trenes:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   [...] Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   com.db4o:db4o-full-java5:jar:7.13-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   com.db4o:db4o-full-java5:pom:7.13-SNAPSHOT
>   from/to source.db4o
>   (https://source.db4o.com/maven/):
>   Error transferring file:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification
>   path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Curiously enough, it only happens in Ubuntu GNU/Linux (tested in two PC's), but not in Windows (using NetBeans 7.0).

I can post the full error (from maven -X output), but I think it does not add much information

**Edit 1:**
This is what I have in my `pom.xml` file regarding db4o:

```
<repository>
  <id>source.db4o</id>
  <url>https://source.db4o.com/maven/</url>
</repository>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.db4o</groupId>
    <artifactId>db4o-full-java5</artifactId>
    <version>7.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a security certificate issue for a secured request which is generally looked up from `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts` . I am *guessing* your `windows JRE` has the entries whereas the `ubuntu JRE` is lacking them.

By the way this [link](http://stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.com/2008/10/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path.html) is a good read on installing certs. You probably want to use the option 1 mentioned there.

Comment: The thing is that I did not install any additional certificate in Windows, esentially because the repository does not ask for any kind of authentication - it's https://source.db4o.com/maven/

Comment: Following your leads and [this tutorial](http://wiki.unisa.edu.au/display/AAI/Add+Certificates+to+your+Java+Keystore), I was finally able to do it. Thanks!